# Return images that belong to same product - SQL SELF JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as the image demonstrate:
[image]

i want to render the images that references same product, my solution is like this:

```
select A.id, B.id, A.product_id
from images A,
     images B
where A.id <> B.id
  and A.product_id = B.product_id
order by A.product_id;
```

but the result is redundant as below:

[image]

the expected result should look like:
[image]

Comment: @Strawberry sorry but i included my own sql query on a real table

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment.

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Would you like any of the entries or one in particular?

Comment: @banana_99 one of the entries never mind

Comment: @Strawberry thnx i will re check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

But the answer to your question is `<`:

```
select A.id, B.id, A.product_id
from images A join
     images B 
     on A.id < B.id and A.product_id = B.product_id
order by A.product_id;
```

If you just want the list of ids, though, you might consider `group_concat()`:

```
select product_id, group_concat(id)
from images
group by product_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: the first one just returns the same result as my proposed solution, the second one do the job but not as desired

Comment: @ELHITFatima . . . The first does **not** return the same as your solution.  The logic is different.

Comment: sorry didn't notice the < operator i used my <> one, thnx it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It gives you a list with all the image paths and ids for each product_id.

```
-- Auxiliary test data
with images (id, image_path, product_id) as (
    select 9, 14, 22 from dual union all
    select 10, 16, 26 from dual union all
    select 23, 7, 4 from dual union all
    select 24, 7, 4 from dual)
-- Actual query
SELECT
    product_id,
    LISTAGG(image_path, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            image_path
    ) AS id,
    LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            id
    ) AS ids
FROM
    images
GROUP BY
    product_id
```